# How do you turn the first (numerical) character of a string into an integer in Java?

Tags: java

So let's say I have a double which is 1.5, and then I convert it to a string, then try to turn the first character into a string using the `char.at` method.

```
double a = 1.5;
String b = String.valueOf(a);
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(b.charAt(0)));
```

But when I did that, here's the output I received:

```
49
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: If one of the answers resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking that as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use Character.getNumericValue(b.charAt(0));
to get actual value instead of ASCII

Answer (score 7):

`valueOf` takes either an `int` or a `String`. You passed a `char` (returned by `charAt`) which got promoted to an integer. You can use `substring` to get the first character of the string instead.

```
double a = 1.5;
String b = String.valueOf(a);
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(b.substring(0, 1)));
```

Answer (score 3):

It's taking the `ascii` value of the first character.

If you want to pass [`Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) a `String` as a parameter, try the following:

```
double a = 1.5;
String b = String.valueOf(a);
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(Character.toString(b.charAt(0))));
```

Also, if you want to pass an integer, [`Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) can also be used as following:

```
double a = 1.5;
String b = String.valueOf(a);
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(Character.getNumericValue(b.charAt(0))));
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: `Character` has a `getNumericValue` method for this: `Character.getNumericValue(b.charAt(0))`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes this also works for sure, but I think  OP wanted to pass a ``String`` as a parameter. I updated the answer to include both techniques.

Answer (score 2):

There are various methods to do this, one is the following (using the `Double` class):

```
Double number = 1.5;
System.out.println(number.intValue());
```

The `intValue()` method will return the `int` representation of the istance of Double

Answer (score 1):

parseInt will work too:

```
double a = 1.5;
String b = String.valueOf(a);
int c = Integer.parseInt(b.substring(0,1));
System.out.println(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

The ASCII value of `'1'` is `49` which is what you are getting. In order to get `1`, you need to subtract `'0'` or `48` (the ASCII value of `'0'`) from it.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 1.5;
        String b = String.valueOf(a);
        System.out.println(b.charAt(0) - '0');
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Character#getNumericValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(int)) to get the numeric value of the character.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 1.5;
        String b = String.valueOf(a);
        System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue(b.charAt(0)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
```